# Animating background-position

Tags: css, css-animations

Hello guys I have this CSS code:

```
  header {
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: url("../img/logo-green-2x.png"), url("../img/hero.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 800px 800px, -1300px -900px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: hsla(300, 100%, 50%, 0.4);
  transition: background-position 0.5s ease;
}

header:hover {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

My problem is that the background images start at position `0px 0px` when I load or refresh the page, why they do not start at the initial position `background-position: 800px 800px, -1300px -900px;`? (More specifically, they start at `0px 0px` and transition to `800px 800px, -1300px -900px` without being in any state)

Comment: Have you checked on multiple browsers? From what you described, it looks like a well-known Chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=398878.
Bit of a workaround here: https://www.hawkbydesign.com/weird-google-chrome-css-transition-on-load-bug/

Comment: I tried Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge but they produced the same issue, what is happening is very weird tbh!